# Laravel Return redirect not working after record imported in DB with array_chunk

Tags: php, mysql, xcode, laravel, laravel-5

Beginner to Laravel,  doing a record import with array_chunk into the database, the problem when record successfully imported in the DB it's not redirecting in the path also if I am echoing the message then it's print 5 times I guess there are 3000 records and chunk of 600.  so its 6 time echoing.

Please help me I don't know what's going wrong with the code or what I have missed here

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Item;
use App\Master;
use Excel;
use Validator;
use Session;
use Image;
use App\Http\Requests;
use DB;
use Auth;
use SuperClosure\Serializer;

class MaatwebsiteDemoController extends Controller
{


    public function importExcel(Request $request)
    {

        if($request->hasFile('sample_file')){

            $path = $request->file('sample_file')->getRealPath();
            Excel::filter('chunk')->load($path)->chunk(600, function($results) 
            {
            foreach ($results as $value) 
            {

               $arr[] = ['DIAMD_NO' => $value->diamd_no,
                              'FULL_TITLE' => $value->full_title,
                              'MAIN_DESC' => $value->main_desc, 
                              'VARIANT_DESC' => $value->variant_desc,
                              'ISSUE_NO' => $value->issue_no,
                              'ISSUE_SEQ_NO' => $value->issue_seq_no,
                              'PRICE' => $value->price,
                              'PUBLISHER' => $value->publisher,
                              'CARDS_PER_PACK' => $value->cards_per_pack,
                              'PACK_PER_BOX' => $value->pack_per_box,
                              'PRNT_DATE' => $value->prnt_date,
                              'FOC_VENDOR' => $value->foc_vendor,
                              'SHIP_DATE' => $value->ship_date,
                              'SRP' => $value->srp,
                              'CATEGORY' => $value->category,
                              'GENRE' => $value->genre,
                              'MATURE' => $value->mature,
                              'ADULT' => $value->adult,
                              'NOTE_PRICE' => $value->note_price,
                              'PAGE' => $value->page,
                              'WRITER' => $value->writer,
                              'ARTIST' => $value->artist,
                              'COVER_ARTIST' => $value->cover_artist,
                              'COLORIST' => $value->colorist,
                              'FOC_DATE' => $value->foc_date,
                              'OFFERED_DATE' => $value->offered_date,
                              'URL'=> $value->url,
                              'created_by' =>Auth::guard('inventoryadmin')->user()->id
                              ];

                }
                 //$count = count($arr);
                 if(!empty(arr))
                 {
                  \DB::table('master_comic')->insert($arr);
                  //  return redirect('inventoryadmin/dashboard')->with('message','Comic Records Successfully Imported');
                    echo "Successfully imported";
                 }
          });


      }
    }
}
```

Comment: move that redirect out of loop...it is running for every chunk processed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a huge array in memory. You should save after every row and put redirect outside of the loop, like this:

```
public function importExcel(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->hasFile('sample_file')) {

        $path = $request->file('sample_file')->getRealPath();
        Excel::filter('chunk')->load($path)->chunk(600, function ($results) {
            foreach ($results as $value) {

                $arr = [
                    'DIAMD_NO'       => $value->diamd_no,
                    'FULL_TITLE'     => $value->full_title,
                    'MAIN_DESC'      => $value->main_desc,
                    'VARIANT_DESC'   => $value->variant_desc,
                    'ISSUE_NO'       => $value->issue_no,
                    'ISSUE_SEQ_NO'   => $value->issue_seq_no,
                    'PRICE'          => $value->price,
                    'PUBLISHER'      => $value->publisher,
                    'CARDS_PER_PACK' => $value->cards_per_pack,
                    'PACK_PER_BOX'   => $value->pack_per_box,
                    'PRNT_DATE'      => $value->prnt_date,
                    'FOC_VENDOR'     => $value->foc_vendor,
                    'SHIP_DATE'      => $value->ship_date,
                    'SRP'            => $value->srp,
                    'CATEGORY'       => $value->category,
                    'GENRE'          => $value->genre,
                    'MATURE'         => $value->mature,
                    'ADULT'          => $value->adult,
                    'NOTE_PRICE'     => $value->note_price,
                    'PAGE'           => $value->page,
                    'WRITER'         => $value->writer,
                    'ARTIST'         => $value->artist,
                    'COVER_ARTIST'   => $value->cover_artist,
                    'COLORIST'       => $value->colorist,
                    'FOC_DATE'       => $value->foc_date,
                    'OFFERED_DATE'   => $value->offered_date,
                    'URL'            => $value->url,
                    'created_by'     => Auth::guard('inventoryadmin')->user()->id,
                ];
                \DB::table('master_comic')->insert($arr);

            }
        });

        return redirect('inventoryadmin/dashboard')->with('message', 'Comic Records Successfully Imported');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller's methods redirect should be outside any loop, it's the last piece of code a controller method should execute ever

```
public function importExcel(Request $request)
{
    // Your import code goes here

    return redirect('inventoryadmin/dashboard')->with('message','Comic Records Successfully Imported');
}
```